# How mix a JQuery slideshow + Accordion?

Tags: jquery

I fall in love with this slideshow for showcase screenshots of my app:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-rotator/

However, if fixed for 6 photos. I want a more flexible solution, so I wonder if is possible for JQuery mix the slideshow with a accordion-type style on the left, so I can put several more photos.

Answer (score 1):

The slideshow does not appear to be limited to 6 images.
It uses

elements to generate the images and create a slideshow from them.

Comment: I mean *visualy*. If I put 8, the desing break.

Comment: Do you want to post the code that you are using when it breaks?